# How to display database information on webpage using Razor-pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

[This is the image of database I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNnWi.png)

I want to display the "word" but using only the "id". If I have the id "11111", I need to display the word "abascus"

This is what I have done so far:

```cs
//This is the code behind file (.cshtml.cs)
public IList<testdiceware> testdiceware { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    testdiceware = await _db.testdiceware.ToListAsync();
}
```

This is how I'm trying to display information

```asp
//This is the .cshtml where I'd like to display the result
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.testdiceware[11111].word);
```

This gives me ArgumentOutOfBounds exception probably cause it's referring to this [value (marked in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1FMQ.png), but I want to display the "word" corresponding to the "id" value

**The main hurdle I'm facing is:**

I'm generating the number '11111' and I need a way to display the corresponding word only using the generated number '11111', is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `testdiceware[index].word`,the value in `[]` should be the index of list testdiceware,you cannot put  `11111` into it.The exception `ArgumentOutOfBounds` is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method.You can try to use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.testdiceware[0].word);
```

to get word of the first `testdiceware`.

**Update:**

you can try to use:

```
@Model.testdiceware.Where(t => t.id == 11111).ToList()[0].word
```

Comment: yep I see why it's going out of bounds, but the constraint is that I'm generating the number '11111' and I need a way to display the corresponding word only using the generated number '11111', is there a way to achieve the following?

Comment: Hello,I have updated my answer about finding the corresponding word with id.